# Drawing plots interactively in a web app

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am looking for a library preferably in JavaScript, that will allow a user to draw a plot (simple one consisting of vertical and horizontal steps) like this one:

[image]

The idea is that when the user is done with the plot I can generate data points from the graph and process them.

I don't know where to start, I am looking to start learning to do this within a JS based framework (meteor) but I can't find a library that allows for something like this. The closest library I found is d3.js but I couldn't find any example that allows for this.

Would anyone be able to point out to me a sample example to start from? Would you know of a better suited library to accomplish what I am asking for?

Comment: I think you should stick with D3.js. It definitly allows to do that but you will need to dig into the (humongous list of) examples and get, if not the right sample, at least elements that allows you to understand how to achieve this. The scale will be the easy part. For the rest, it should not be too hard either. Sorry I couldn't help more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ckrg29bc/) is a relatively simple fiddle which accomplishes some of what you asked for, excluding axis (which are relatively easy and has plenty of examples). It uses D3 for all the drawing and mouse event handling. On click it simply executes `svg.append("circle").attr("r", 5)`, and if it's not the first click (i.e. linking points) then it also will create a `path` element using the previous mouse click coordinates:

```
svg.insert("path", "circle").attr("d", function () {
        return [
            "M", prevClickLoc[0], prevClickLoc[1],
            "L", prevClickLoc[0], y,
            "L", x, y].join(" ");
    })
```

Where `x` and `y` are the current mouse coordinates. Also has an export button that will output a list in the form of `cx,cy,cx,cy,... :: d,d,d,d,...`. On import, you could easily split this array into two using `indexOf("::")` or whatever you choose if you want to change the formatting. Then just exectue `for (x in circles) {svg.append("circle").attr("cx", function...).attr("cy", function...);}` and do something similar for paths `for (y in paths) {svg.append("path").attr("d", function(){return paths[y];});}`. It would be even easier if on export you made the `cxcy` array in the format `cx;cy,cx;cy` since then you could simply `split` the array at each comma and then split each index of the resulting array at the semicolon for a nice nested array.

[Small update](http://jsfiddle.net/ckrg29bc/2/) in this version, you can only place points if the current mouse x is greater than the previous x coordinate, and it also has the line `d3.event.stopPropagation();` which prevents accidental highlighting of the page.